# OpenWhisk support of websockets and static websites

Tags: websocket, ibm-cloud, single-page-application, openwhisk

I'm choosing a serverless platform for my projects. I have explored AWS and found it excessively complicated: they provide an enormous bunch of settings but some basic scenarios are been too hard to implement.

The other platform looking promising for me is IBM Cloud with its OpenWhisk. And I'd like to check if the necessary capabilities are either implemented or in close plans for implementation.

### Questions

1. Can I use websocket for my functions as a trigger for connect, message and disconnect? I found only a half year old discussion and nothing more. But this feature is demanded for real time applications.
2. Can I have static websites in both my custom domain and in subpath? I saw recipes where a docker container and lambda functions were employed. But writing my own implementation of Nginx looks nonsense. But this feature is also strongly demanded for single page applications (SPA) and there can be multiple such SPAs on one domain.

Answer (score 0):

This [blog with an IBM Cloud Functions overview](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/a-recap-of-the-key-advantages-offered-by-ibm-cloud-functions) has links and answers to your second question.  There are tutorials on how to use custom domains with IBM Cloud Functions as backend for applications (see this [tutorial with static page / SPA custom domain](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/tutorials?topic=solution-tutorials-serverless-api-webapp), and recipes for [Express](https://github.com/IBM/expressjs-openwhisk) and [Flask](https://github.com/alexmilowski/flask-openwhisk)).

[IBM Cloud Functions also has a package to post to Websockets](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=cloud-functions-pkg_websocket). AFAIK there is functionality to listen to Websockets. My understanding is that serverless is incompatible with the "always on" nature of [Websockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) and the serverless runtime would need an API gateway or similar to manage the communication. If something is received, the action would be invoked.

Comment: This is not exactly what I wanted to know. (1) I would like to get a ref. not to IBM's blog, but to a page where the deployment of a static website is discussed. (2) A package to POST websocket messages to some other websocket server may be important for someone but I wanted to get a solution for my backend application.

And also I do not see a problem with handling websocket serverless. And AWS also has realized this functionality. WS required only permanent TCP connection but not a permanent function. And this is the duty of a provider to keep this connection. Not a customer.

Comment: You can wish for it, but this is what I provide as my answer. The links to custom domain and recipes are in the answer. For AWS, Websockets is part of the API Gateway, not Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Support for websockets for the ActionLoop proxy (used by Go,Swift,Python,PHP,Rust and Java) is here: https://github.com/sciabarracom/incubator-openwhisk-runtime-go/tree/websocket-support.

It can be used to build runtimes that support websocket but you need to deploy the runtime by yourself using Kubernetes. The support had ben postponed as an integration of OpenWhisk with Knative is a better path to include it in OpenWhisk.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you're linking back to a GitHub account you're associated with, could you please disclose that in your answer? Please take a moment to read Stack Overflow's [self-promotion guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)